# Failed to get default firebase instance in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As I was working on my iOS app, I got this error out of no where
`` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRAppNotConfigured', reason: 'Failed to get default Firebase Database instance. Must call `[FIRApp configure]` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) before using Firebase Database.' ``

on the line initializing `DB_BASE`

```
    var DB_BASE = Database.database().reference()
    
    class DataService {
        
        static let instance = DataService() 
}
```

I have `FirebaseApp.configure()` in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` `AppDelegate` function, so I'm not sure what the error is all about. I've tried updating pods, restarting my computer, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Database specifically, but we use Storage, Analytics and Remote Config. Have you put google-services.json to the root of the project?

The code you provided doesn't make it totally clear, but if DB_BASE by any chance is a member of a singleton (like DataService.instance), try moving it to a different place. Static variables get inited before applicationDidFinishLaunching is called.

Comment: DB_BASE is not a member of a singleton, tried moving the variable around but still no luck

Comment: Hm, then edit your question and add more scope please. Is DB_BASE a global variable or something? Try using it in some local scope.